# How does the this wildcard work "* .*"

Tags: bash, wildcards

Here are the outputs.

```
echo  *.*
file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt

echo * .*
file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt . ..
```

Why does the second command include the files if they have no space character before the period? Thank you for the help much love!

Comment: Did you try `echo *` and `echo .*` separately? You should be able to see what is happening from those outputs.

Comment: [This page](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Filename-Expansion.html) should help fill the gaps, so to speak.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Those are two separate globs. The first, `*` matches everything except hidden files, so that prints out `file1.txt`, `file2.txt`, and `file3.txt`. The second, `.*` matches hidden files and directories only: those whose name starts with a `.`, so this prints out `.` and `..`.

If you only want to print out file/dir names with a space followed by a period, you would need to escape the space so that it isn't treated as a separator:

```
$ ls
 file1.txt  'file2 .txt'
$ echo *\ .*
file2 .txt
```

Finally, I should probably mention that the `*.*` doesn't mean "match everything". Unlike in Windows systems, *nix systems don't require an extension to file names (with very few exceptions, extensions are completely optional and arbitrary). On *nix systems, the `*.*` glob will only print file names with a `.` in their name:

```
$ ls
 file   file1.txt  'file2 .txt'
$ echo *.*
file1.txt file2 .txt
```

To print all files, use a single `*`:

```
$ echo *
file file1.txt file2 .txt
```

Comment: Alterately, quote the space instead of a backslash: `echo *" ".*`

Answer (score 1):

Parameters to commands are separated by spaces, unless they're quoted .

```
 echo *.*
```

matches filenames with "any characters" (`*`), followed by a dot (`.`), followed by "any characters" (`*`).

```
 echo * .*
```

The 1st pattern matches filenames with "any characters" (`*`). The 2nd pattern ("`.*`") matches filenames that begin with a dot (`.`), followed by "any characters" (`*`). These "dotfiles" are NOT matched by `*`, which is why they're often called "hidden" files.

The two entries you see ("`.`" and "`..`") are the required links to the current and parent directories.

Dealing with filenames containing spaces and other "funny" characters (only `NUL 0x00` and Slash `/` are forbidden in filenames) is complex (Read `man find xargs`) and should be avoided, if possible.

There are a couple of the many ways of quoting a space in a filename, each with slightly different details:

```
echo *\ .*
echo *" ."*
```